# mysql sort accordint to two fields, then renumber the "id" column

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a 5 column table (columns are  id , answer, weight, quiz_id and  question_id)
 and I would like to sort it by question_id, then sort by weihgt, then I would like to renumber the id column incrementally according to this double sorting.
Is it possible in mysql (I am using phpmyadmin)?

thanks

something like:

```
SELECT 
   @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS id,
   T.Answer, T.Weight, T.Quiz_Id, T.Question_Id
FROM wp_wpss_Answers T
   JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
ORDER BY QuestioN_Id, Weight
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

Comment: Do you want to update your ID column in the db or just show the new row number?  Not sure why you would be updating your ID column -- set to an identity and let MySQL increment it accordingly.

Comment: I want to update the ID column

Comment: this is a bad idea.  a database does not need to be renumbered in general - it will cause you more headaches than any perceived benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want to show the row number with your query, then use something like this:

```
SELECT 
   @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS RowNumber,
   T.Answer, T.Weight, T.Quiz_Id, T.Question_Id, T.Id
FROM YourTable T
   JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
ORDER BY QuestioN_Id, Weight
```

If you're wanting to update your ID, you can use the above, but I'd ask why are you doing this?  I can't see any reason to renumber your ID columns -- set it to an Identity and let MySQL handle it.

However, to update your Id column, try something like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
  JOIN (SELECT 
       @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS RowNumber,
       T.Answer, T.Weight, T.Quiz_Id, T.Question_Id, T.Id
    FROM YourTable T
       JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
    ORDER BY QuestioN_Id, Weight) T2 ON T.Id = T2.Id
SET t.Id = T2.RowNumber
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ac3f/1).

But you really should reconsider this approach.

Good luck.